Function with a constant rate of change on the relative interior of a convex cone of $\mathbb R^n$ which has empty interior
Let $V$ a convex cone of $\mathbb{R}^n$ having an empty interior. Let $relint(V)$ denote its relative interior.
Let $f:V \to \mathbb{R}$. Assume that for all $v \in relint(V)$, $$\lim_{t\to0}\: \frac{f(v_1,...,v_k+t,...,v_n)-f(v_1,...,v_k,...,v_n)}{t}=a_k \in \mathbb{R},$$
that is, the rate of change of $f$ in any coordinate is constant on $relint(V)$.
Is it true that on $relint(V)$, $f$ is the restriction of an affine map $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ ?
I know that if $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, with $\Omega$ nonempty, open and connected in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is differentiable and has constant partial derivatives on $\Omega$, then it is indeed the restriction to $\Omega$ of an affine map (Constant derivative of a function implies is an affine map.) but the problem is here different as $V$ has an empty interior in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

At least some of those limits are not going to be well-defined. If, for all $k$, you have $(v_1, \ldots, v_k + t, \ldots, v_n) \in V$ for sufficiently small $t$, then this implies $(v_1, \ldots, v_n) \in \operatorname{int} V$, due to the convexity of $V$. How do we deal with the $k$s for which this limit does not make sense?

Isn't $0\in V$ in the definition of a cone? If not, what definition are you using?

I'm confused, because even if $\mathbf v=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is in the relative interior, that doesn't mean $(v_1+t,v_2,\dots,v_n)$ is in $V,$ even for $t$ small.

If $\mathbf w_1,\dots,\mathbf w_k$ are elements of $V$ which form a basis  the span of $V,$ then you can say if $\mathbf w=\sum a_i\mathbf w_i$ is in the relative interior, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for each $i$ and $|t|<\epsilon,$ $\mathbf w+t\mathbf w_i$ is in the relative interior of $V.$

So your actual condition might need to be be that there is a function $\phi:V\to \mathbb R$ such that for each $w$ in the relative interior and $v\in V: $$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(w+tv)-f(w)}t=\phi(v)$$ You can easily show that $\phi(v_1+v_2)=\phi(v_1)+\phi(v_2)$ and $\phi(\alpha v)=\alpha \phi(v),$ I think.

Thanks a lot for your help. Considering your last comment, am I right to say that you are defining a directional rate of change, in all the admissible directions in $V$, and replace my assumption by the assumption that for all $w \in relint(V)$, the directional rate of change in direction $v$ at $w$ does not depend on $w$ ?
Then, if $\phi$ is indeed additive and positively homogeneous on $V$, this should imply that $f$ is the restriction of an affine map ?

Right - the only directional changes you can make in the  (relative) interior and still stay in the interior is  in a direction $v\in V.$ You could restrict it to a basis $v_1,\dots,v_k$ of the span of $V$ and just assert $\lim\frac{f(w+tv_i)-f(w)}{t}=a_i$ for $i=1,\dots,k,$ I believe.

And contrary to my initial claim, I can't find an obvious proof that $\phi(v_1+v_2)=\phi(v_1)+\phi(v_2).$ Proving that is the crux of the problem, I think.

Thanks a lot @ThomasAndrews. I have two observations/questions, if I may:


In your comment above, should not it be "You can easily show that $f(w_1+w_2)=f(w_1)+f(w_2)$ and $f(\alpha w)=\alpha f(w)$" ?


How can I actually prove that the fact that $lim \frac{f(w+tv_i-f(w))}{t}=a_i$ for all $i$ implies $f$ being positively homogeneous and additive ?



No, I mean $\phi$ there, but I'm not sure $\phi(v_1+v_2)=\phi(v_1)+\phi(v_2)$ is easy to prove.
